# Write data to Redshift using Spark 2.0.1

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, amazon-redshift

I am doing a POC, where I want to write some simple data set to Redshift.

I have following sbt file:

> 

```
name := "Spark_POC"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.10.6"


libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-core_2.10" % "2.0.1"

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-sql_2.10" % "2.0.1"

resolvers += "jitpack" at "https://jitpack.io"

libraryDependencies += "com.databricks" %% "spark-redshift" % "3.0.0-preview1"
```

and following code:

```
object Main extends App{

  val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Hello World").setMaster("local[2]")

  System.setProperty("hadoop.home.dir", "C:\\Users\\Srdjan Nikitovic\\Desktop\\scala\\hadoop")

  val spark = SparkSession
    .builder()
    .appName("Spark 1")
    .config(conf)
    .getOrCreate()


  val tempS3Dir = "s3n://access_key:secret_access_key@bucket_location"

  spark.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3n.impl", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3native.NativeS3FileSystem")
  spark.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3n.awsAccessKeyId", "access_key")
  spark.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3n.awsSecretAccessKey", "secret_access_key")

  val data =
    spark
      .read
      .csv("hello.csv")

  data.write
    .format("com.databricks.spark.redshift")
    .option("url", "jdbc:redshift://redshift_server:5439/database?user=user_name&password=password")
    .option("dbtable", "public.testSpark")
    .option("forward_spark_s3_credentials",true)
    .option("tempdir", tempS3Dir)
    .mode("error")
    .save()
}
```

I am running the code from local Windows machine, thru Intellij.

I get the following error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Could not load an Amazon Redshift JDBC driver; see the README for instructions on downloading and configuring the official Amazon driver.

I have tried with almost all the versions of Spark-Redshift drivers, (1.0.0, 2.0.0, 2.0.1 and now 3.0.0-PREVIEW) and I can't get this code to work.

Any help?

Answer (score 1):

You first need to download the [Redshift JDBC driver from Amazon](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/configure-jdbc-connection.html#download-jdbc-driver).

Then you must tell Spark about it in the environment where this code is running. E.g. for a `spark-shell` running on EMR:

```
spark-shell … --jars /usr/share/aws/redshift/jdbc/RedshiftJDBC41.jar
```

Comment: I am not running the code on EMR, I am running it thru Intellij on my laptop, by clicking the run button. 

Any idea about that?

Comment: Yeah, the EMR thing is just an example. I don't know about IntelliJ specifically but you basically just need to tell the JVM it's running about the location of this jar.

Comment: I used this Jar https://s3.amazonaws.com/redshift-downloads/drivers/jdbc/1.2.20.1043/RedshiftJDBC42-no-awssdk-1.2.20.1043.jar but I am still getting an exception `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Failed to find data source: com.databricks.spark.redshift`. Probably the suggested Jar is not enough?