# Include aws jdbc driver while running spark application

Tags: maven, apache-spark, amazon-redshift

I am trying to pull data from redshift in a spark application.I included some dependency and i was able to do that in my local machine. But i get the following error when i try to run the application on Amazon EMR.
The following is the command i am trying to execute:

```
spark-submit --class classname --packages com.databricks:spark-avro_2.11:3.0.0,com.databricks:spark-redshift_2.11:2.0.1,com.databricks:spark-csv_2.11:1.5.0,com.amazon.redshift:redshift-jdbc41:1.2.1 --deploy-mode client /mnt/firstRun.jar
```

It throws the following error:

```
::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::

::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

:: com.amazon.redshift#redshift-jdbc41;1.2.1: not found

::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

:: USE VERBOSE OR DEBUG MESSAGE LEVEL FOR MORE DETAILS
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: [unresolved dependency: com.amazon.redshift#redshift-jdbc41;1.2.1: not found]
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmitUtils$.resolveMavenCoordinates(SparkSubmit.scala:1066)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.prepareSubmitEnvironment(SparkSubmit.scala:294)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:158)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:124)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
Command exiting with ret '1'
```

I know that there is something wrong in the way i have given the jdbc driver package. I did so because my maven dependency is:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.amazon.redshift</groupId>
  <artifactId>redshift-jdbc41</artifactId>
  <version>1.2.1.1001</version>
</dependency>
```

I defined the package in the form of groupId:artifactId:version.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: The `--packages` option provides maven coords, but that package isn't in maven.  You will have to supply the jar another way, such as bundled with your fatjar.

Answer (score 1):

I think the answer is the same as my answer here [Write data to Redshift using Spark 2.0.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40931864/write-data-to-redshift-using-spark-2-0-1/40998152#40998152)

Basically, if you're not running on EMR, you'll have to download the JDBC driver and put it somewhere that Maven will find it.

On EMR it's already in place so you can just reference it like

```
spark-submit …blah… --jars /usr/share/aws/redshift/jdbc/RedshiftJDBC41.jar
```